# Reminder of questions that you have asked but have not selected an answer for

Tags: feature-request, notifications, unanswered-questions

There has been many times when I got a notification of an upvote on one of my questions, and I notice that I haven't selected an answer yet. Even if I eventually used one of the posted answers; I just forget to select an answer sometimes. Does stackoverflow have a system for pushing notifications to users to remind them of questions that they have asked but have not selected an answer for?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature, but you can instead perform a search with the following query:

```
user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1) will give you all your questions  which have at least one answer but no accepted answer.